# Explain this CSS custom properties behavior

Tags: css, css-variables

I'm struggling to understand the following with CSS variables, I believe the code speaks for itself otherwise please let me know.

```css
:root {
    --color: red;
    --hover-color: var(--color);
}

div {
    --color: green;

    background: var(--color);
}

div:hover {
    background: var(--hover-color);
}
```

```html
<div>
Why am I red on hover? Shouldn't I be green? When inspecting this element on hover, chrome shows the green color!?
</div>
```

What's absolutely baffling to me is that when inspecting the element in Chrome Devtools it shows the hover color as green??

[image]

Comment: Do other browsers handle it differently? It's either a bug (within Chrome), or the variables are set by reference rather than by value.

Comment: Same behavior in Mac Firefox.

Comment: an important rule: never do evaluation at root level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--hover-color` resolves to the `--color` value of the scope in which it exists, meaning it will compute the value detected at that time. This is to avoid dependency cycles. You can read about [these cycles in the specification document](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#cycles).

> Custom properties are left almost entirely unevaluated, except that they allow and evaluate the `var()` function in their value. This can create cyclic dependencies where a custom property uses a `var()` referring to itself, or two or more custom properties each attempt to refer to each other.

To prevent this, you would want to expand a bit, and do the following:

```css
:root {
    --color: red;
    --hover-color: var(--color);
}

div {
    --color: green;
    --hover-color: var(--color); /* Added this here */

    background: var(--color);
}

div:hover {
    background: var(--hover-color);
}
```

```html
<div>
I am green on hover, as expected.
</div>
```

But this raises an interesting issue with Chrome's DevTools, which indeed shows a green color preview next to the hover state's background value. You might want to [file an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) and have this looked into.

Comment: Oh I see. It's a little annoying we need to reset both `--color` and `--hover-color`, and really weird that Chrome shows it as green, but I can live with it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I don't understand why you are refering to cycles here?

Comment: Now devtool can display the correct value. Looks like chrome has fixed this.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing is , you are making a variable then passing color to it , purely my thinking don't know this is the reason or not

Let's say its a javascript variable , then

```
var color = red;
var hoverColor = multiplier * color;
```

Then , you passed

```
color  = green;
```

Then in hover , what happening is

```
hover = hoverColor;
```

(i.e. hoverColor = someMultiplier * color & color is green)

Comment: CSS variables/properties are completely different to most other language's variables though. I understand why this would happen with JS.